# Protecting test selectors from outside Page Objects

Tags: cypress

I'm building page objects for the team to use in Cypress tests. The idea is to encapsulate the selectors so that when they change I update in one place and everyone's tests remain functional.

The problem is the class fields are accessible /modifiable from the tests. How do I prevent access to the selectors directly?

Example PO:

```js
class ProductPage {
  
  product: string = 'select#product'
  productOptions: string = 'select#product option'

  selectProduct(productName) {
    cy.get(this.product).select(productName);
  }
}

export const products = new ProductPage();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use hash names (fields starting #) to protect the class inner fields.

You should also separate declaration and initialization of the fields.

```js
class ProductPage {
  
  #_product: string 
  #_productOptions: string

  constructor() {
    this.#_product = 'select#product'
    this.#_productOptions = 'select#product option'
  }

  selectProduct(productName) {
    cy.get(this.#_product).select(productName);
  }

  // product only has a getter, so is immutable
  get product() {
    return this.#_product   
  } 
}

export const products = new ProductPage();

products.selectProduct('apple').then(...

cy.get(products.product).then(...
```

Added example getter for outside access.

Comment: Fody, Can I make my object literal properties immutable like this?

Comment: Yes, you need to add a getter since private fields are both immutable *and* invisible.

Comment: Refer to [Using getters in classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get#using_getters_in_classes)